# rails server failed to install twitterbootstrap gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

When i am trying start the rails server i am hitting the following error 
after trying to force install twitter bootstrap gem

**Could not find gem 'therubyracer (~> 0.10.2) x86-mingw32, 
which is required by gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails (>= 0) x86-mingw32 
in any of the sources.**

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is your OS? Is it windows? Try to run this command

```
   $gem install -f --ignore-dependencies  twitter-bootstrap-rails --platform ruby
```

Comment: @jhon.smith did it work for you ? unfortunately not working for me :(

Comment: @Cyclone, maybe you can use Static Bootstrap gem?


gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails', :git => 'git://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails.git', :branch => 'static'